# Not getting the output for JSON.strigify()

Tags: javascript, json, web-deployment, stringify

Here I'm trying store the name of the id and the number of times it has been clicked.

It's stores as an object  but when I tried  `JSON.Stringify()` it returns a empty array like this
'[]'

```js
if (localStorage.getItem('cart') == null) {
  var cartArr = {};
} else {
  cartArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
}



const cartClass = document.querySelectorAll(".cart");
cartClass.forEach((ele) => {
  ele.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let cartId = (e.target.getAttribute('id'));
    if (cartArr[cartId] == undefined) {
      cartArr[cartId] = 1;
    } else {
      cartArr[cartId] += 1;
    }
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cartArr));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code, it works correctly. Your problem can be solved by cleaning your `localStorage`. It seems that at some point you have stored an empty array into your local storage. What happens is, `JSON.stringify` stores the contents of array, but ignores any custom properties you set on an array object:

```js
// This will log "[]"
const arr = [];
arr.prop = "val"
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));

// This will log {"prop": "val"}
const obj = {};
obj.prop = "val"
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. You never stored an array in that code. Perhaps you have another code that stored cart as an array?

I would delegate and give the system a tiny bit of time to react

```js
const cartStr = localStorage.getItem('cart')
cartArr = cartStr ? JSON.parse(cartStr) : {}
const cartContainer = document.getElementById("cartContainer");
cartContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest(".cart");
  if (tgt) {
    let cartId = tgt.id;
    cartArr[cartId] = cartArr[cartId] ? cartArr[cartId] : 0;
    cartArr[cartId]++;
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cartArr));
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(localStorage.getItem('cart'))
    }, 10); // give the system time to react
  }
});
```